# sqliteDB on Django server is locked after python script INSERT command

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a Django sqliteDB that is served for two purposes-

1. The Django website is based on it
2. A python script that adds records to that DB

When I run the website and the python script everything works fine, UNTILL I try to modify the website info **after the python script has run**.

I can't seem to figure out what process still locks the DB because I'm using commands that are supposed to close it...

*Sorry in advance for the screenshots. I'm running the code on a different PC and I'm connected to it using AnyDesk...*

This is the code I'm using in the python script:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Maybe I'm just asking too much from the SQLite DB? Or am I not closing still open connections?
I didn't encounter these problems when I ran it back on my PC, So I don't seem to understand what changed.

Comment: No unreadable code screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if SQLite has an option for multiple connections, but I gave up on trying to make that and converted my DB to Postgres :-)

There is a nice
https://sweetcode.io/django-postgresql-migration-from-sqlite/tutorial in this URL-